# GLIBCXX 3.4.29 not found in linux 22.04

Tags: gcc, electron, libstdc++

Running

```
 strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

In my terminal shows me this:

Output:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
```

to
GLIBCXX_3.4.32
GLIBCXX_TUNABLES
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

When I run:

```
strings /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

output is:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
```

to
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

All related questions solutions I tried, but none of them work fine.

I am facing problem when I am running my electron app.

The following error it shows:

```
my-electron-app@28.1.0 start
electron .

/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /home/kartik/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
[11062:0127/154407.668862:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[11062:0127/154407.670354:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
[11062:0127/154407.680482:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!
^C/home/kartik/Pictures/my-electron-app/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGINT
```

I dont know Why this king of error arre only found in my system only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you installed your vscode from snap store. then you need to  uninstall it and then download .deb file from vscode website and run it , it will run fine.